# Dynamic name tablе in trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a trigger that copies columns from one table to another. How do I assign a table name to a dynamic variable `@nametable`? 
Every day the name of the table changes depending on the current date.

```
USE dbo;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `update_test`;

GO

DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER `update_test` AFTER INSERT ON `hello_send`

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DECLARE nametable VARCHAR(128);

SET @nametable =(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%d%m%Y_v"));

    INSERT INTO `dbo`.`nametable` SET
      `TIME_` =NEW.`recorded`,
      `P1` = NEW.`value1`
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        `TIME_` = NEW.`recorded`,
       `P1` = NEW.`value1`;

END;
```

Have error `ERROR 1146: Table 'dbo.nametable' doesn't exist`

Comment: Have a look at [Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) - But what you are trying to do looks like a bad idea.

Comment: This seems to be a really bad design choice. Create a table every day and fill it with a trigger? That's something that you should avoid at all costs.

Comment: Piling on the "really bad design choice" a table for every day? How about one table with the date as it's own column for that record? Your headed down a very very painful path with this design.

Comment: There is an external application that works with these tables and to which I can not affect, the data per day is saved in a separate table whose name is the current date + _v.

Comment: Maybe I'm going the wrong way, but I need to write the data in the already available table A from Table B. Are there any other options?
Prepared SQL Statement The syntax for me is still complicated since I'm just starting to learn SCL. I will be very grateful to help me.

Comment: There is even an example with a dynamic table name. But the bad news: "SQL syntax for prepared statements can be used within stored procedures, **but not in** stored functions or **triggers**."

Comment: This an absolutely bad idea, Your triggers is just inserting a new record from the other table otherwise update if exists but why you need to create a new table with a dynamic table name? You are just getting a head  bangs on the wall.

Comment: I need a dynamic table name to embed values ​​into a table that every day has a different name.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to do so as a temporary solution:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_test` AFTER INSERT ON `hello_send`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET @dateNameTableNOW =(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%d%m%Y_v"));
SET @dateNameTableSELECT1 = '06122017_v';
SET @dateNameTableSELECT2 = '07122017_v';
IF(@dateNameTableNOW = @dateNameTableSELECT1) THEN
 INSERT INTO  dbo.06122017_v  SET TIME_=NEW.recorded, P1 = NEW.value1 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE TIME_ = NEW.recorded, P1 = NEW.value1;
END IF;

IF(@dateNameTableNOW = @dateNameTableSELECT2) THEN
 INSERT INTO  dbo.07122017_v  SET TIME_=NEW.recorded, P1 = NEW.value1 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE TIME_ = NEW.recorded, P1 = NEW.value1;
END IF;


END;
```